# C++ Сортировать массив по количеству повторяющихся элементов

Tags: c++, массивы, сортировка

Сортировать массив по количеству повторяющихся элементов. Значение элемента не важно.

Например: до `3 0 5 1 0 0 3 3 5 3 1` после `3 3 3 3 0 0 0 5 5 1 1`

Мой код (часть другого кода поэтому переменные не инициализированы) 
Я создал 2 массива в одном единичные экземпляры элементов в другом количество этих элементов соответственно, но ничего не получилось -(-_-)/-

```
sort(mas_dbl,mas_dbl+m); \\ что-бы сгруппировать числа вместе  (1 2 0 0 6 1)--->(0 0 1 1 2 6)
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
cout<<mas_dbl[i]<<" ";
}
cout<<endl;cout<<endl;

int d=0;
int f[s];
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
f[i]=0;
}
int p=0;
int temp;
for(int i=0; i<s; i++)
{
if ((mas_dbl[i])==(mas_dbl[i+1])){p++;}
else{ f[d]=p+1;d++;p=0;}}

for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
{
cout<<f[i];
}
cout<<endl;cout<<endl;
int v=0;
for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
{
if ((mas_dbl[i])!=(mas_dbl[i+1]))
 {v++;}
}
int mas_dbl2[v+1];
int y=1;
mas_dbl2[0]=mas_dbl[0];
for(int i=1; i<s; i++)
{
if ((mas_dbl[i])!=(mas_dbl[i+1]))
 { mas_dbl2[y]=mas_dbl[i+1];y++;}
}
for(int j=0; j<v+1; j++)
{
cout<<mas_dbl2[j]<<" ";
}

int t=0;
for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
{
if (f[i]<f[i+1])
 {temp=f[i+1]; f[i+1]=f[i]; f[i]=temp;
   temp=mas_dbl2[i+1];
     mas_dbl2[i+1]=mas_dbl2[i];
     mas_dbl2[i]=temp;}
}
for(int i=0; i<d; i++)
   for(int j=0; j<f[i]; j++)
{
cout<<mas_dbl2[t];t++;
}
cout<<endl;cout<<endl;
```

Comment: Добавьте отступы в код и укажите, что значит "ничего не получилось".

Answer (score 0):

А обязательно все вручную? Раз сортируете стандартным алгоритмом - допускаю, что и стандартные контейнеры можно использовать... Тогда можно, например, [так](https://ideone.com/tmPOtd):

```
int main()
{
    map<int,int> m;
    multimap<int,int,greater<int>> mm;

    for(int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
    {
        int v = rand()%20;
        m[v]++;
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    for(auto v : m)
        mm.insert(make_pair(v.second,v.first));

    for(auto v : mm)
        for(int i = 0; i < v.first; ++i)
            cout << v.second << " ";
    cout << endl;

}
```